# How to update sphinx MVA attributes with the PHP-API?

Tags: php, sphinx

We are using Sphinx 2.0.1-beta and want to update MVA-Attributes with the PHP-API.
After the method call this error appears, but when i use the command line tool to verify that the index-update succeeded i just get this error message:

**"search error: out of pool memory on loading persistent MVA values."**

So the update doesn't work as expected.

1. In the [searchd]-section of /usr/local/sphinx/etc/test.config we inserted:

mva_updates_pool = 128M

1. Then we implemented a class to update sql_attr_uint values, which works very fine. In order to use MVA-values, we extended this class a little bit.

When we debug our code with the PHP-API-file,

```
function UpdateAttributes ( $index, $attrs, $values, $mva=false )
        {
                // verify everything
                assert ( is_string($index) );
                assert ( is_bool($mva) );

                assert ( is_array($attrs) );
                foreach ( $attrs as $attr )
                        assert ( is_string($attr) );

                assert ( is_array($values) );

                foreach ( $values as $id=>$entry )
                {
                        assert ( is_numeric($id) );
                        assert ( is_array($entry) );
                        assert ( count($entry)==count($attrs) );

                        foreach ( $entry as $v )
                        {
                                if ( $mva )
                                {
                                assert ( is_array($v) );
                                foreach ( $v as $vv )
                                assert ( is_int($vv) );
                                var_dump($vv);
                                } else
                                assert ( is_int($v) );
                        }
                }
...
```

we are getting values for $vv after the if($mva) test.

1. An example of the data-structure, we use as argument for the update function:

Pseudo-Code:

```
$attrs:
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "attributeKey"
}
```

$values:

```
array(2) {

    [182371746]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            int(1)
            [1]=>
            int(10)
        }
    }

    [182371749]=>
    array(1) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
            [0]=>
            int(2)
            [1]=>
            int(11)
        }
    }
}
```

Method call:
$sphinxClient->UpdateAttributes('destinationIndex', $attrs, $values, true);

The method call returns '3' (for the amount of updated documents (0 or more) on success, or -1 on failure).

Has someone any ideas why this error occurs?

Comment: I gave an answer but then saw it didn't really apply to your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message says that there were many updated MVA attributes and you run out of MVA pool memory.

Comment: Yes, the problem is, i set MVA pool memory to 128M and updated only five or six attributes. It's impossible to use so much RAM by doing this.

Comment: Maybe you have updated them in a loop or any complex pattern? As it not always possible to reclaim memory of freed attributes.